# AWS: Configure Cognito Users to assume a specific IAM role to execute Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have implemented Cognito User pool based authentication for the API gateway.

I want to provide access to specific AWS resources based on Cognito user.

As per the link below I am thinking to implement user creation/authentication flow.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-group/

**User Creation Flow**

1. For every user, I am planning to create a new Cognito user.
2. There will be a new IAM role created.
3. A new Cognito user group will be created with this IAM role.
4. The Cognito user will be added to this group.

**User Authentication flow**

After the user is authenticated, the user will use the ID token for subsequent API calls.

Based on this ID token, the user name and the IAM roles will be extracted.

The Lambda function will assume this role and execute the code.

There is a soft limit of 300, on the number of groups which can be created per Cognito user pool.

**Queries -**

1. Is there any better/optimised flow which can be used to implemented?
2. Can I assign a IAM role for every Cognito user, without creating a new Cognito user "group"?
3. I am assuming, this soft limit of 300 on the number of user groups per user pool, can be increased by sending a request to AWS.

Comment: What resource are you planning to give access to?

Comment: What is the reason to create new IAM role for each user? Each user should have different permissions?

Comment: I am thinking to create separate DynamoDb tables per tenant. So for every tenant there will be a corresponding IAM role, through which I will be able to control the access to DynamoDB tables.